# How can I expand/collapse an EditText when I click on it?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-edittext

I want to create an animation to expand an EditText when I click on it(to a height set by me), and when it loses focus(I click on something else) it should collapse back to one line. This is what I tried, but it kinda does nothing..

```
public class CollapseDownAnimation extends Animation {
    private EditText mDescription;
    private boolean mDown;

    public CollapseDownAnimation(EditText description, boolean down) {
        this.mDescription=description;
        this.mDown=down;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation transformation) {
        int newHeight;
        if(mDown) {
            newHeight=(int) (300 * interpolatedTime);
        } else {
            newHeight=(int) (300 * (1-interpolatedTime));
        }
        mDescription.getLayoutParams().height=newHeight;
        mDescription.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}

EditText mDescription;
mDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        CollapseDownAnimation anim = new CollapseDownAnimation(mDescription, mDescription.hasFocus());
        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG, "the focus is "+mDescription.hasFocus());
        mDescription.setAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: did you try TextInputLayout ???

Comment: you can change number of lines programmatically on changing of focus of edit text